# Whhat is the meaning of given below code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

The question is to take 4 integers as input entered in separate lines.
ex:=

```
1
1
1
2
```

The below code does the required thing. I am trying to understand its working part.

```
x,y,z,n=[int(input()) for _ in range(4)]
```

Comment: And what exactly is it that you don't understand? Do we need to explain `input()`? `int()`? `range()`? list comprehensions? unpacking assignments?

Comment: Sorry, I am a beginner in Python.

Answer (score 1):

welcome!

This code is the equivalent of

```
x = int(input())
y = int(input())
z = int(input())
n = int(input())
```

The `input()` function reads an input from the user and the `int` tries to transform it to an integer, which is assigned to each variable (`x`,`y`, `z` and `n`).

The code can be also written as:

```
numbers = []
for i in range(4): # Loop 4 times
 numbers[i] = int(input())

x = numbers[0]
y = numbers[1]
z = numbers[2]
n = numbers[3]
```

Which is more similar to the form you provided. But the author uses two python features that makes the code smaller (and more expressive). I'll explain both:

1. [List Comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Lot of times during programming, you will be whiling to execute a command several times and get the results into an list, or for example, map values from one list to other. In this case, you would have something like this:

```
numbers_til_5 = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
squares_til_5 = []
for n in numbers_til_5:
  squares_til_5.append(n*n)
```

With the List Comprehension syntaxe, we could do:

```
sqaures_til_5 = [ n*n for n in numbers_til_5]
```

The other feature is:

2. [Destructuring](https://riptutorial.com/python/example/14981/destructuring-assignment)

This is a feature that allows you to get elements of a list in one single statement.
In the example we have this:

```
x = numbers[0]
y = numbers[1]
z = numbers[2]
n = numbers[3]
```

Which could be replaced by `x,y,z,n = numbers`. 
Another form interesting, is when you care only for the first arguments, for example:

```
first = numbers[0]
rest = numbers[1:] # This get all elements starting from the first
```

could be written as `first, *rest = numbers`.

I hope I was able to make it clear.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was quite helpful.

Answer (score 0):

`for _ in range(4)` repeats `int(input())` 4 times, so the brackets contain now the first four inputs `[1, 1, 1, 2]`.

In Python you can assign multiple variables at one time, so x,y,z and n will be assigned to the corresponding values of the bracket.

For better understanding, you could extract the individial parts like this:

```
x = int(input())
y = int(input())
z = int(input())
n = int(input())
```

Answer (score 0):

It is running a loop to input values as integers and feeding those values to the variable x,y,z,n in that sequence. range(n) runs the loop for a range 0-n (in this case, 4 times). _ is used to denote "anything" while running the loop.